# When I click on dropdown it will show the data on textbox from the database. When I try to save the fields in the page it should save in database

Tags: javascript, textbox

I have Javascript code for onchange event when I click on dropdown  it will show  the data on textbox from the database. Here my problem is when I  try to save  the fields in the page . it has to save in database ...  here I am getting save like customerno and customename as same( eg: customerno=12345 and customername=12345)

```
<script>
function custname(){
    var cno=document.returnname.customerdp.value;
    document.getElementById('cnoname').value=cno;
}
</script>
```

**PHP File:**

```
<label>Customer:</label>
<select name="customerdp"  onchange="custname()">
     <?php
         $sql=mysql_query( "select acc_name,acc_no from cs_details") ;
         while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
         {
     ?>        
             <option value='<?=$row['acc_no'] ?>'> <?=$row['acc_name'] ?></option>";
     <?php
         }
     ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Things that I didn't understand: **1)** you select acc_name and acc_no from database and put them in a drop box. Are those vals the same? **2)** if not, you mentioned you want save fields in database. Can you show us how you insert these values to your database?

Comment: where's the code that writes to a database?

Comment: i have database called cs_details in that i have fields like customerno and customername... this two fields have different records , so when i select in dropdown list  the relavent data of customername will be displayed on textbox  and  i have one button called save . when i click save button both  dropdown and textbox data will save in database.